# Inno Setup and Permissions for non-admins: everyone, users, or authusers?

Tags: permissions, uac, inno-setup, acl

Should I give "modify" permissions to 'everyone' or 'users' or 'authusers' if, under UAC, I want to make data folders and files writable to non-admin users of the program?

I want that basically everyone who can sit at the computer can read/write the data through the program. I've also read that using 'everyone' for modify permission can open a security hole over the network. What is the difference between everyone, users, and authusers? What are the security implications?

Implementation details for InnoSetup follow:

Using InnoSetup, I install an EXE in a standard Program Files subfolder, and a Data subfolder within it, like this:

C:\Program Files\My Prog\Prog.exe
C:\Program Files\My Prog\Data\MyData.dat

Now, to make it so that MyData.dat can be modified by Prog.exe even if Prog.exe is launched by a non-admin users, I give "modify" permissions to the subfolder "Data" with this line:

```
[Dirs]  
Name: "{app}\Data"; Permissions: everyone-modify;  
;This is the question: should I use users or authusers instead of everyone?  

[Files]  
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: replacesameversion;  
Source: "MyData.dat"; DestDir: "{app}\Data"; Flags: replacesameversion;
```

This question is similar to [2686918](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686918) but I didn't find enough info there about the types of permissions, hence this new one. I'll update that question after clarifying this one.

InnoSetup in particular defines these groups:

- admins Built-in Administrators group
- authusers Authenticated Users group
- everyone Everyone group
- powerusers Built-in Power Users group
- system Local SYSTEM user
- users Built-in Users group

Which of those is the nearest to "any user who is sitting at the machine, admin, non-admin, or whatever, but nobody who is accessing the machine from networks"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going the wrong way! Don't store your application data under `%PROGRAMFILES%`! Use the directory which is intended for this: [CSIDL_APPDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Consult Microsoft, if you want to have more informations about the [security identifiers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330).

Comment: Thanks. I've done this before, and in some cases my prog hasn't been able to access some of those folders. Hence the idea of using a data-only subfolder in ProgramFiles and giving if modify permissions. (permission to modify the data subfolder, not the folder with installed exe), and it seems to work fine so far... And even if I use ProgramData instead, I still need to set the Permissions of the particular subfolder I use, so I'm still trying to understand whether to use everyone, users, or authusers, or what else...

Comment: Thanks, perhaps can you give us one more pointer... Can you kindly see my edit about InnoSetup's list of SIDs and recommend which of those is the closes to "everyone who sits at the computer, and nobody else"... thanks!

Comment: I think the description of the "Everyone" group matches your requirement: "A group that includes all users, even anonymous users  and guests. Membership is controlled by the operating system."

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with "Everyone" than. This help was very appreciated!

Comment: To avoid problems with permissions if use InnoSetup, use ``Name: "{app}"; Permissions: everyone-modify users-modify authusers-modify powerusers-modify admins-modify`` not only for everyone group, this will resolve write problems which is forbidden for users group by inheritence from **c:\Programs files** folder. Consider first how sensitive is your app on tampering, if it is a crypto wallet for example it would be bad idea giving wide access to everyone, but in my case is not a problem.